# How to compute these Riemann-Stieltjes-Integrals?

Tags: integration, analysis

I have some doubt on this exercise which I have to solve:

Compute The Integral $\displaystyle \int_0^4 F(x) \ \mathrm{d}G(x)$ for

1.) $F(x) = x$ for $x<2$, $1$ otherwise; $G(x)=x^2$

2.) $F(x) = e^{-x}$ ; $G(x) = 0$ for $x<2$, $4$ for $2≤x<3$ and $-2$ otherwise.

3.) $F(x)=(1+i)^{\lfloor -x\rfloor}$ with $i$ in $(0,1)$; $G(x) = 0$ for $x<0$, $1$ for $0≤x<1$, $2$ for $1≤x<2$ and $\sin(\pi \cdot x)$ otherwise.

On 2.) I think the integral will be $0$ because $F$ is continuous, $G(x)$ is constant and there are no common discontinuity points between $F$ and $G$.

On 3.) There are common discontinuity points like $0,1,2$. So there doesn't exist an Integral.

Now my question is, how to find the integral in 1.)? Because $F$ is not continuous but $G$ is continuously differentiable. So $\mathrm{d}G(x)=G'(x)\mathrm{d}x$.
I tried to calculate the integral in two parts. One from $0$ to $2$ and the other one from $2$ to $4$. But There does not exist a value $F(x)=x$ for $2$. So I don't how to compute the first integral.
How can I solve this problem?
Am I right in 2.) and 3.)?

Comment: Continuity is not necessary for integrals. The [Dirichlet Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) is discontinuous yet integrable.

Comment: ad 1) Whay do xou think that F(x) does not have a value at 2? It is 1.

Comment: @zoli Yes, it is. But I wanted to try to integrate the function from 0 to a number which is still defined in the 1st case, i.e. a number smaller than 2. And then integrate the function from 2 to 4 for the 2nd case. I don't get an idea how to solve it in another way.

Comment: @Reasoner Could one just integrate it from 0 to 4 straight away? I'm not sure because of the discontinuity point 2.

Comment: 1) $\int_0^4F(x)dG(x)=\int_0^2x(2x)dx+\int_2^42xdx$

Comment: 2) At 2 and 3 $G(x)$ jumps. That is, those two points have weight... So are you sure that 2)=0?

Comment: 3) To be honest, I don't understand $F(x)=(1+i)^{-x}$. Is it, say, $\frac{1}{(1+05)^x}$?

Comment: @zoli I exactly got this integral! So I'm on the right way?

Comment: @zoli But in 2 G(x) is constant on every point right? And there is a theorem that says if G(x) is constant for every x then the integral will be 0. Am I not allowed to use that? In 3 F(x) and G(x) have the same discontinuity points and so you can't compute an integral. Can I?

Comment: @zoli In 3 "-x" is in a Gauss bracket, which will take the largest integer smaller than the value.

Comment: Gaussian bracket $\lfloor x\rfloor$ ? Then: \lfloor x\rfloor.

Comment: @zoli Thanks, I've edited it. I got now the first integral. But I'm still not sure about 2 and 3 if my argument is correct.

Comment: OK. I'll risk to answer in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the definition and the basic existence theorems of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral see p.ex. the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

(1) If the derivative of the integrator is continuous, like in the case of our $G(x)=x^2$, then the Riemann-Stieltjes integral can be calculated as a Riemann integral:
$$\int_0^4F(x)\frac{dG(x)}{dx}dx=2\int_0^2x^2dx+2\int_2^4xdx=\frac{52}{3}.$$

(2) Let $0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n=4$ be a partition of $[0,4]$. And let $$\Delta G_i=G(x_{i+1})-G(x_i).$$
An approximation of our Riemann-Stieltjes integral is
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{-c_i}\Delta G_i$$
where $c_i\in[x_{i},x_{i+1}]$, for all $i$. Since
$$G(x)=\begin{cases}
\ \ \ 0 \text{, if } x<2\\
\ \ \ 4 \text{, if } 2\le x<3\\
-2\text{, if } 3\le x
\end{cases},$$
we have $$\Delta G_i=\begin{cases}
\ \ \ 4 \text{ if } 2\in (x_i,x_{i+1}]\\
-6 \text{ if } 3\in (x_i,x_{i+1}]\\
\ \ \ 0 \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

As a result
$$\int_0^4e^{-x}dG(x)=4e^{-2}-6e^{-3}.$$

(3) If there are points where both $F$ and $G$ are discontinuous then the R-S integral is not well defined. Even so, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of our function exists.

Comment: Now I got it. So in 2) you can always use this approximation when you have discontinuity points in G?

Comment: The approx was only a definition based explanation. The rule is -- vaguely -- that if the integrator has jumps where the integrand behaves then the L-S integral (at those places) multiplies the integrands values by the jump values of the integrator.